# Send a binary excel file data from memory stream and generic handler to client side and prompt save

Tags: c#, jquery, excel, epplus

Currently I am using JQuery AJAX and connect it to the Generic Handler (.ashx), inside the Generic Handler, I am doing the template for the Excel File that is going to save the computer (prompt save). i can achieve that while using the .aspx.cs , the reason I am doing from Generic Handler (.ashx), is because I don't know any way to hide the loading overlay after the dialog box for us to save to the computer is appear. (means the loading overlay just stick there). `$(element).show()` or `$(element).hide()` is to show or hide the loading overlay.

I am using **EPPlus Library** to generate the template for Excel File, however I don't know how to pass the object into client side and then prompt to save, it keeps gives me an error.

The problem I was encountered while using the Generic Handler is always gives me the parsererror message.

Here is the code that I am using:

**JQuery AJAX:**

```
var loading = $("#loading");

$("#template").click(function () {
            loading.show();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "TemplateService.ashx?Month=" + $("#Month").val() + "&Year=" + $("#Year").val(),
                data: {},
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    loading.hide();

                    console.log(data);

                    alert("Success");
                },
                error: function (xhr, text) {
                    loading.hide();

                    console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText));
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(text));

                    alert("There is a problem while processing your request");
                }
            });
        });
```

**Generic Handler (.ashx):**

```
public class TemplateService : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    private int Month = 0;
    private int Year = 0;

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Month = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Params["Month"]);
        Year = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Params["Year"]);

        try
        {
            string MonthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(Month);

            string fileName = string.Format("{0} - {1} {2}.xlsx", "Excel Template", MonthName, Year);

            using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                package.Export();

                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    context.Response.Clear();
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));

                    package.SaveAs(stream);

                    stream.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);

                    context.Response.Write(stream);
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            ProcessResponse(context, Response());
        }
    }

    private string Response(bool isSuccess = false)
    {
        string status = (isSuccess) ? Constant.SUCCESS : Constant.FAILED;

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            Status = status
        });
    }

    private void ProcessResponse(HttpContext context, string response)
    {
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Write(response);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Export function:**

```
public void Export(this ExcelPackage package)
        {
            try
            {
                package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Excel Template");

                var workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Excel Template"];

                var columnNames = new string[]
                {
                    "First Column",
                    "Second Column",
                    "Third Column"
                };

                var headerRow = new List<string[]>()
                {
                    columnNames
                };

                var cells = workSheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, 3];

                cells.LoadFromArrays(headerRow);
                cells.AutoFilter = true;
                cells.AutoFitColumns();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
<form>
<asp:Button ID="Submission" runat="server" OnClick="Submission_Click" Text="Upload" />
<input type="button" id="Template" value="Template" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var loading = $("#loading");

   $("form").submit(function () {
        loading.show();
    });

   $("#template").click(function () {
            loading.show();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "TemplateService.ashx?Month=" + $("#Month").val() + "&Year=" + $("#Year").val(),
                data: {},
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    loading.hide();

                    console.log(data);

                    alert("Success");
                },
                error: function (xhr, text) {
                    loading.hide();

                    console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText));
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(text));

                    alert("There is a problem while processing your request");
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Your answer much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Since you're handling this from an ASHX file, what is the purpose of the JavaScript AJAX call? Can't you just have a link with the URL (that includes any appropriate ID)?

Comment: Hi, please see the updated question, I have included the HTML as well. The purpose of the AJAX call is for the loading to show up and hide. Because I am using when form is submit, then show the loading overlay, and when the process is finished from server side, the loading bar automatically hide. But, when I am using the server side for Template, the loading overlay will always show up, even though the process is already finished (means the data already being downloaded and stored in computer). Thanks

Comment: For your second inquiry, I can use like I saw from forum while search online for my problem. `<a href="TemplateService.ashx?Month=02&Year=2018">`, but I can't use the loading overlay anymore. I tried to call the loading overlay to show up on server side by like `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "$(document).ready(function () { $("#loading").show()  }", true);` or hide when it is already finish, but it can't show nor hide.